# bent tabular rear control arm

Tags: toyota, corolla, control-arm

I have a 1995 toyota corolla. It has a tubular rear control arm that is bent.  It also has rear toe adjustments that are threaded and seized.  How hard will it be (and how long will it take) to straighten that arm and free up my toe adjustments so I can have the car aligned.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Do you mean replace and align? About an hour and a half off the top of my head. Depending on if the bolts are seized to the sleeves etc...